# Use Google Apps Script to Conditionally Format One Cell If Text Is Matched By Another Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Spreadsheet whose first four columns (A, B, C, D) are dynamically imported from a separate master Spreadsheet.

Columns E, F are designed to take static inputs based on the dynamic data in the columns to their left.

Column A contains an individual's name.

I want to use column G as a static reference to column A to ensure the inputs in columns E & F can be easily maintained in the correct rows via manual cut and paste when the dynamic data in columns A through D move as new inputs arrive from or are removed from the master sheet.

To do this, I want a script that 'conditionally formats' the entries in column G when they match those in column A (bold, italicize, color the text), AND does not fall afoul of the issue associated with cutting and pasting using the standard UI conditional formatting in google sheets, where a cut and paste will 'break' the conditional formatting range.

We'll copy the values in dynamic column A over to static column G and then reference back to A using conditional formatting.

I have a basic script here (gleaned from another stackoverflow poster), but it is going to need some work to do what I need it to do.

```
function onEdit() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("A:G");
var values = range.getValues();

//for each row that data is present
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
var cell = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 7);

//check if the first value of that row is exactly "Client Name"
if(values[i][0] === "Client Name") {

//if it is, check for "Client Name" in the same row in G [6].  If so, make 
it green.

if(values[i][6] === "Client Name") {
    cell.setBackground('green');
  } else {
    cell.setBackground('white');
  }

} else {

//In any other case, make it white.
cell.setBackground('white');
}
}   
}
```

I want the script to check if the value in cells A3:A are equal to those in G3:G and if they are to format the text in G3:G as indicated.

A "mock up" of sheet with existing script is here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13iPM83I5ecskuBaBin8hepTyBqD29ng0Zp3e6DBcuEk/edit?usp=sharing

**Thanks for all help!**

Comment: If you use conditional formatting in google sheets, and you cut and paste values between conditionally formatted rows/columns, the range of the conditional formatting ends up broken.

More here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/wzafBCllE7M

Comment: ...and here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/3zHwtO3AxAU

Comment: The issue is we are trying to ensure that when A and G don't match G is effectively highlighted so we know something is wrong, and can adjust the static inputs accordingly. So, yes, it matters to me. Our volume and pace is large and quick. We need visual cues that are clear and effective.

Comment: What matters to me is the formatting stays consistent after a dynamic input is removed, and the static inputs are then cut and pasted to ensure they correlate to the remaining dynamic input, without having to go in and repair the conditional formatting each time this happens (likely many times in a single day).

Comment: Even with whole column references the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your conditional formatting to use the custom formula

```
=AND($G1=$A1, NOT(ISBLANK($A1)))
```

and then you use "Paste values only" (Edit > Paste special or `cmd + shift + v`, `ctrl` if on Windows), then you will not need a script.

Using conditional formatting and pasting values will be much faster.

Otherwise, you can use this script for changing the formatting in column G when it doesn't match the respective value in A.

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // getActiveSheet() can yield unexpected results
  var rangeA = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  var rangeG = sheet.getRange("G:G");
  var valuesA = rangeA.getValues();
  var valuesG = rangeG.getValues();
  var backgrounds = []; // Create an array for the background colors
  var fontColors = []; // Create an array for the font colors

  //for each row that data is present
  for(var i = 0; i < valuesA.length; i++) {
    var aValue = valuesA[i][0];
    var gValue = valuesG[i][0];
    if((aValue != "") && (gValue === aValue)) { // If value in A is NOT blank AND A == G
      backgrounds.push(["green"]); 
      fontColors.push(["white"]);
    } else {
      backgrounds.push([null]); // Using null will reset the background color formatting
      fontColors.push([null]); // Using null will reset the font color formatting
    }
  }  
  rangeG.setBackgrounds(backgrounds); // Set the background colors all at once for speed.
  rangeG.setFontColors(fontColors); // Set the font colors all at once for speed.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Diego! I’ll try this shortly & see what happens.

Comment: If I understand the issue correctly, then it's one I've experienced many times before, and is entirely resolved by using copy/paste-values.

Comment: Thank you Diego. Your custom formula did exactly what I was looking for.